# How to call a .nb notebook inside a another notebook

Tags: notebooks, packages, options

I generally use .m as the file for mathematica. However currently I have started using .nb interface and its looking good.
However if I create separate .nb files and try to call/import them inside my master notebook, I can not do that. Is there a way to do that?

The current solution I am getting from another website (https://www.researchgate.net/post/Importing_and_running_nb_file_inside_another_in_mathematica2)
is the following:

```
nb1 = NotebookOpen["~/filename.nb"];
SelectionMove[nb1, All, Notebook]
SelectionEvaluate[nb1]
here goes the calls from the imported notebook
NotebookClose[nb1]
```

But this is not very efficient, since its literally opening and closing the second notebook and also I have to keep my calling etc. inside the open and close block. 
In .m interface I . can simply import. The reason I am wanting is that .nb is good looking (at least for Greek letters) and I want to have everything as this format.
Any help?

Comment: Have you looked at NotebookEvaluate?

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed.